# How can I find out a cpu model name on Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to find out how to get cpu model name and vendor for a long time but with no success, I've tried using cat `/proc/cpuinfo` and I was searching in `/sys/` files.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/cpuinfo` is the correct way to access the CPU information. How are you trying to read it?

Try this:

```
 private String ReadCPUinfo()
 {
  ProcessBuilder cmd;
  String result="";

  try{
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    System.out.println(new String(re));
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
  } catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: Yes I've tried it but the needed information is not there. It's there on my PC but not on my Galaxy Nexus